# PHP cURL API problem with nested arrays and http_build_query

Tags: php, curl, put

Got cURL code working on terminal to change the forwarded phone number on an online SIP service (don't have access to the REST API server-side):

```
curl --request PUT --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Basic abcdefABCDEFmysecretkey123456" -d '{"forwardings":[{"destination":"+447979123456","timeout":0,"active":true}]}' --header "Content-type: application/json" https://api.sipgate.com/v2/w0/phonelines/p0/forwardings
```

However my efforts to replicate this code in PHP are resulting in an `{"error":"cannot parse content"}` response:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$churl='https://api.sipgate.com/v2/w0/phonelines/p0/forwardings';
$chdata = array(
    'forwardings' => array(
        'destination' => '+447979123456',
        'timeout' => 0,
        'active' => true
    )
);
$chdata2 = http_build_query($chdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $churl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-type: application/json",
    "charset: utf-8",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Basic abcdefABCDEFmysecretkey123456"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $chdata2);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
echo $json;
curl_close($ch);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `http_build_query ` encodes the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The data in your CLI cURL statement is JSON however, and that is even what you made the `Content-Type` header say.

Comment: No, I am suggesting that you actually _send_ JSON, and not just a Content-Type header that _says_ you were, when in fact you aren't really.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think `json_encode` does not properly handle nested arrays?
When I change `http_build_array($chdata)` to `json_encode($chdata)` (which I actually tried first), the server response changes to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token` - this is what made me pivot towards http_build_query

Comment: json_encode handles them fine, you simply did not manage to provide the correct input data structure to begin with. You are missing one array level in your data. `'forwardings' => array(...)` needs to be `'forwardings' => array( array(...) )`.

Comment: You are right - that solved it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want to repost that as an answer so I can "accept" it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [from comments} I might be wrong, but I think json_encode does not properly handle nested arrays?

json_encode handles them fine, you simply did not provide the correct input data structure to begin with.

You are missing one array level in your data. `'forwardings' => array(...)` needs to be `'forwardings' => array( array(...) )`

---

BTW/FYI/for anyone who might ever need it: An easy way to *get* the data structure you need, already in form of usable PHP code, based on the existing JSON, would be a combination of var_export and json_decode:

```
var_export(json_decode('{"forwardings":[{"destination":"+447979123456","timeout":0,"active":true}]}', 1));
```

gets you the following result,

```
array (
  'forwardings' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'destination' => '+447979123456',
      'timeout' => 0,
      'active' => true,
    ),
  ),
)
```

So you can slap a `$chdata =`  in front of that and a `;` at the end, and done.

Answer (score 0):

Since the content-type is set to JSON, its expecting the data you pass to be json encoded.

Try replacing

```
$chdata2 = http_build_query($chdata);
```

With

```
$chdata2 = json_encode($chdata);
```

**UPDATE with @CBroe comment**

Change the $chdata array to be

```
$chdata = array(
    'forwardings' => array(
        array(
            'destination' => '+447979123456',
            'timeout' => 0,
            'active' => true
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think `json_encode` does not properly handle nested arrays?
When I change `http_build_array($chdata)` to `json_encode($chdata)` (which I actually tried first), the server response changes to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token` - this is what made me pivot towards http_build_query